# Prepositions conflict in the same sentence

Tags: preposition

I’ve never seen before *anstatt* together with other prepositions. Is it possible to use it in conjunction with the others i.e. *anstatt* + *vor*?

> Es ist ratsam, Mineralwasser beim Essen zu konsumieren, anstatt es vor der Mahlzeit zu trinken.

Comment: Aehm, yes? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: position of anstatt when it is needed to use with vor

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence is an answer of a Question like:

> “When should one drink Water …?”,
>   “Wann ist es ratsam Mineralwasser zu trinken …?”

with the addition (or focus on the timing)

> *vor* dem Essen oder *beim* Essen?

and maybe the exact Question was:

> Ist es ratsam Wasser vor der Mahlzeit zu trinken oder kann man es beim Essen trinken?

So as you may see the preposition *vor* has nothing to do with *anstatt* in your case! The preposition is related to the time when one should drink water, *before* the meal or *at* the meal!

Answer (score 2):

It’s advisable, to consume water *during* meals, instead of drinking *before* meals.
*anstatt/instead* is referring to the whole part *vor der Mahlzeit trinken*, while *vor/before* is part of it indicating the temporal relation.

> Es ist ratsam, Mineralwasser beim Essen zu konsumieren, anstatt vor der Mahlzeit trinken.

It’s fine this way, but the sentence lacks a *zu* before *trinken.*

> Es ist ratsam, Mineralwasser beim Essen zu konsumieren, anstatt vor der Mahlzeit zu trinken.

In any way, it sounds translated, because *konsumieren* is rarely used in conjunction with water.

Comment: "anstatt" requires always "zu" i think

Comment: Indeed. As in English, it requires an infinitive if verbs are included.

Answer (score 2):

There are two prepositional phrases that are in contrast to each other:

> "beim Essen" versus "vor der Mahlzeit"

I shorten the sentence for simplicity

```
Verb    | Prepositional Phrase | Conjunction | Prepositional Phrase
Trinke    beim Essen             anstatt       vor dem Essen.
```

So, *anstatt* and *vor* are not joint to a single preposition. They are completely independent from each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you use the so-called [*da-compounds*](http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Da/Da.html):

> Es ist ratsam, Mineralwasser beim Essen zu trinken anstatt **davor**.

Comment: very nice advise Elena, and to build like following example also very hard to me,could you please another advise?
Anstatt “übertragenen” muss man “übertragenden” schreiben.

Comment: What does this have to do with your question here? Both are valid forms, but different ones. Which form you choose depends entirely on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you parse this sentence wrong. "anstatt" is not used here with "vor". "Anstatt" is used here with "**vor der Mahlzeit trinken**". 
Compare: "... instead of **drinking before meal**".

Comment: you mean i should consider the whole phrase: "vor der Mahlzeit trinken"  not only the preposition: "vor" :-/ ?

Comment: @Bergmann Yes. "Anstatt" refers to the whole phrase.